# asset_packing tiny_mce files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I use inplacericheditor plugin and tiny_mce

Before asset_packager usage, this is how I include the files and they work well

```
<script src="/javascripts/patch_inplaceeditor_1-8-2.js" type="text/javascript">    
</script>
<script src="/javascripts/patch_inplaceeditor_editonblank_1-8-2.js" type="text/javascript" </script>
<script src="/javascripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/javascripts/tiny_mce_init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/inplacericheditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My asset_packager.yml section looks like this for the above files:

- tinyeditor:

  - patch_inplaceeditor_1-8-2
  - patch_inplaceeditor_editonblank_1-8-2
  - tiny_mce/tiny_mce
  - tiny_mce_init
  - tiny_mce/langs/en
  - tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template
  - tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en
  - tiny_mce/plugins/save/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/autoresize/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/paste/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/preview/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/table/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/contextmenu/editor_plugin
  - tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/editor_plugin
  - inplacericheditor

When I include the asset_packaged file and load the page (in production)
I get the following errors:

"Ajax.InPlaceEditor is undefined"
"Ajax.InPlaceRichEditor is not a constructor"

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong or share a better way to asset_package tinymce?

Thanks!

Comment: Update:
I have included
<%= javascript_include_merged :prototype %> on top of all the script files

Comment: @haries:- <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> includes following js automatically.1] prototpe 2] effect 3] dragdrop 4] control 5] application

Comment: In <%= javascript_include_merged :prototype %>, 'prototype' is the name of the section where I include all the files that you mentioned. So it is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax required prototype.js

try Following just after tiny_mce_init.js

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<script src="/javascripts/inplacericheditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: this doesn't help as I already had included 'defaults' at the top

Comment: yes but it is possible sometimes the two javascripts get conflict and so they don't workout together.So i just recommended that you should put that below the "tiny_mce_init.js". Hope that helps :)